# How to install google tag manager SDK into swift project

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager

Im trying to install the google tag manager sdk into my iOS app using swift. I've followed the instructions here 
[Getting Started Guide for Swift](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/swift#add-bridging-header). On Section 3:Add a bridging header for Objective-C libraries. Step 7: Add these import statements to the header file:. I tried importing code into my bridging header file but when I try and build it comes up with an error that reads `'TagManager.h' file not found.` - How do I solve this error and use google tag manager in swift?

Comment: I'm having the same error, Could you solve it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had checked Googledeveloper site given in your link.Give it a try by just adding your project name inftont of the BridgingHeader.h in **Build Settings** it may work. Eg: **HippiTap**/BridgingHeader.h

**UPDATE: Tag Manager 5.0.6**

1. At last found the reason for this issue,google has updated its TagManager pod file but not updated its tutorial
2. If you use **pod 'GoogleTagManager’** in your pod file it will install the latest available pod **(i.e)5.0.6**
3. This version does't contain necessary file to import in BridgingHeader.h file as shown in https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/swift#add-bridging-header.If we use 5.0.6 pod file in xcode will look like below,

   [image]
4. To solve this we have to reduce the version of TagManager.Now replace

   ```
   pod 'GoogleTagManager’
   ```

   with

   ```
   pod 'GoogleTagManager’,’~> 3.15.0’
   ```

   Now run **pod intall** in your terminal,

   ```
   Installing GoogleTagManager 3.15.0 (was 5.0.6)
   ```
5. By changing the version of tag manager we are free to go by google's tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/swift#add-bridging-header) .
6. Now the pod file will look like below

   [image]

   I think this may help you.give it a try and let me know the result.

Comment: I'm having the same error and doing that I can not resolve it.

Comment: Thank you @ Gokul vivid, I changed the version to 3.15.0 and now works without problem. ;)

Comment: Does this mean we can never use the newest GTM for iOS?

Comment: Not like that,there may be new steps to integrate the latest version i'am not aware of that.Check [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/#prerequisites) link it will give some basic knowledge about latest version

Comment: Yeah, but how de we actually use GTM5 then?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/).google updated their guide for V5.

Comment: pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0' is what I see in the tutorials now.