# After updating pod file, In Header 'GoogleTagManager/TAGManager.h' file not found coming in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-tag-manager

I have pod file in my app, It has old version of library called "GoogleTagManager".
After updating it to latest version, It is throwing below error in BridgingHeader_h file.

'GoogleTagManager/TAGManager.h' file not found

Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Which version were you using, which one are you using now? Did you checked if there has been any changes on that lib that would have removed, rename this header?

Comment: @Larme earlier it was 3.5.0, now I make it to latest version. Then it is throwing error while tried to run the code, I have added the screenshot too.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment so adding it as an answer:
@Larme is correct, GoogleTagManager v7.4.0 does not have any header named "TAGManager.h", screen shot attached

links that can be helpful:

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After long day spent on this issue, I found solution from below link.
At last found the reason for this issue, google has updated its TagManager pod file but not updated its tutorial.

So followed below link solution, I fixed the issue.

[How to install google tag manager SDK into swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315267/how-to-install-google-tag-manager-sdk-into-swift-project)